# How can I unwrap an array from JSON file with python?

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following JSON:

```
{u'messagetype': u'writefft', u'fftData': [[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0]]}
```

How can I unwrap this so I can print each data of the array 'fftData'?

Tried:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
fftData = (data["fftData"])
print (data["fftData"])
```

But I doesn't achiev what I need...

> - What this prints:
> - [[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0]]
> - What I want to print:
> - 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0
> - Tried: print (fftData[0])
> - Put it prints:[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0]

Can someone help me?

Comment: What if the data is `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way:

```
print(', '.join(str(i) for i in data["fftData"][0]))
```

The sneaky way:

```
print(str(data["fftData"]).strip('[]'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`[[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0]]` is a list with a list as its first element.

Instead, extract the inner list out by:

```
fftData = data["fftData"][0]
```

which will now print `[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 0]`

Then, to print out your list, I'd just convert it to a string, then remove the first and last characters by slicing the string.

```
print(str(fftData)[1:-1])
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but unfortunately I'm leading with values that contains a giant float number/numbers with '-e'. Do you know another way to print what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question and provide an example? What do you mean by -e? I don't think that should affect the results. The code should still work for this case--unless you want to do something special for the large numbers.

Comment: '-e' of '*10ˆx'. I'll update my question but thanks.

Comment: I didn't see the update. Could you post the full example?

Answer (score -1):

```
for value in data["fftData"][0]:
    print(value)
```

Comment: That does not do what OP has asked.

Comment: This will not include the commas.

Comment: How can I unwrap an array from JSON file with python?